# ColorPicker implementation using JavaScript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, color-picker

I'm trying to implement ColorPicker using Canvas just for fun. But i seem lost. as my browser is freezing for a while when it loads due to all these for loops.
 I'm adding the screenshot of the result of this script:
[image]

`window.onload = function(){
    colorPicker();
}

function colorPicker(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("colDisp"),
    frame = canvas.getContext("2d");

var r=0,
g=0,
b= 0;

function drawColor(){
   for(r=0;r<255;r++){
      for(g=0;g<255;g++){
         for(b=0;b<255;b++){
            frame.fillStyle="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
            frame.fillRect(r,g,1,1);
         }
      }
   }
}
drawColor();`

Currently , i only want a solution about the freezing problem with better algorithm and it's not displaying the BLACK and GREY colors.
Please someone help me.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link with what you have done?

Comment: hi @micnic here's codepen link: http://cdpn.io/Ebghn

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling fillRect for every single pixel, it might be a lot more efficient to work with a raw RGBA buffer. You can obtain one using [context.getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29), fill it with the color values, and then put it back in one go using [context.putImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29).

Note that your current code overwrites each single pixel 255 times, once for each possible blue-value. The final pass on each pixel is 255 blue, so you see no grey and black in the output.

Finding a good way to map all possible RGB values to a two-dimensional image isn't trivial, because RGB is a three-dimensional color-space. There are a lot of strategies for doing so, but none is really optimal for any possible use-case. You can find some creative solutions for this problem on [AllRGB.com](http://allrgb.com/). A few of them might be suitable for a color-picker for some use-cases.

Comment: i dont understand... How will u use getImageData() when there's no source to get the respective rgb values??

Comment: @LucyJaa When you do it on an empty canvas, you will get RGBA values of 0, 0, 0, 0 (don't forget to set the alpha-value to 255 or the result will be transparent). Alternatively you can use createImageData to create some empty image data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch the rgba of the pixel under the mouse, you must use context.getImageData.

getImageData returns an array of pixels.

```
var pixeldata=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Each pixel is defined by 4 sequential array elements.

So if you have gotten a pixel array with getImageData:

```
// first pixel defined by the first 4 pixel array elements

pixeldata[0]  =  red component of pixel#1
pixeldata[1]  =  green component of pixel#1
pixeldata[2]  =  blue component of pixel#1
pixeldata[4]  =  alpha (opacity) component of pixel#1

// second pixel defined by the next 4 pixel array elements


pixeldata[5]  =  red component of pixel#2
pixeldata[6]  =  green component of pixel#2
pixeldata[7]  =  blue component of pixel#2
pixeldata[8]  =  alpha (opacity) component of pixel#2
```

So if you have a mouseX and mouseY then you can get the r,g,b,a values under the mouse like this:

```
// get the offset in the array where mouseX,mouseY begin

var offset=(imageWidth*mouseY+mouseX)*4;

// read the red,blue,green and alpha values of that pixel

var red =   pixeldata[offset];
var green = pixeldata[offset+1];
var blue =  pixeldata[offset+2];
var alpha = pixeldata[offset+3];
```

Here's a demo that draws a colorwheel on the canvas and displays the RGBA under the mouse:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/94BAQ/

Comment: Superb! Muchos, muchos gracias!  I really like jsfiddle responses, they save so much time searching through responses.

Answer (score 1):

A way to go, using `.createImageData()`:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("colDisp");
    var frame = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var imagedata = frame.createImageData(width, height);

    var index, x, y;

    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            index = (x * width + y) * 4;

            imagedata.data[index + 0] = x;
            imagedata.data[index + 1] = y;
            imagedata.data[index + 2] = x + y - 255;
            imagedata.data[index + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    frame.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0);
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGcaF

Comment: please explain this line  index = (y * 255 + x) * 4; @micnic

Comment: and one more doubt... If i change the width and height of the canvas, will it affect the result?

Comment: the `image.data` is an unidimensional array with `rgba` values and you have to get and index transformed from the x and y coordinates, to not have any problems with the canvas dimensions I updated my answer