# Get byte[] from <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an html canvas, like so:

```
//output is a base64string of image data
var oldImage = new Image();
oldImage.onload = function () {
  var resizeRatio = oldImage.width / 500;
  var height = oldImage.height / 2;
};
oldImage.src = output;
var standardizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
standardizedCanvas.setAttribute("width", "500px");
standardizedCanvas.setAttribute("height", height + "px");
standardizedCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, frontCanvas.width, frontCanvas.height);
```

So I can read the image into the canvas, and then get the Image Data. But what does that really give me? I need a `byte[]` from the canvas, which contains the image data, so really I want to convert a `base64` string into a `byte[]`. Am I on the right track, or....?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041851/converting-bytes-to-an-image-for-drawing-on-a-html5-canvas

Comment: I'm confused about what are you trying to do? In general `.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)` is a way to get an array containing the red, green, blue & alpha values for every pixel on the canvas. Here's a previous SO answer explaining the format of the pixel array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637324/colorpicker-implementation-using-javascript-and-canvas/22641173#22641173

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `getImageData` returns an `ImageData` object.

Documentation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData

The `data` property of an `ImageData` object is is a byte array of length 4*width*height.

The pixels are ordered top left to bottom right a row at a time, with each pixel be represented by 4 bytes, red, green blue and alpha.